# Embedding of spheres which satisfies intersection rules

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, combinatorial-optimization

Let $S = \{S_1, \dots ,S_n\}$ be a finite set of $d$-dimensional spheres with the same radius, and let $E$ be a combination of intersections between them, where an intersection is a rule of the form $S_i \cap S_j \subset S_k$. Given any number of spheres and any combination of intersections, is it always possible to find a configuration of spheres embedded in $\mathbb R^d$ which satisfies all and only the intersections in $E$? Hence, this configuration must not contain any intersection that is not present in $E$.

Side question:

If the answer is negative, but dependent on the dimension, is the following true: Given any number of spheres and any combination of intersections, **there exist a finite dimension d** such that is it always possible to find a configuration of **d**-dimensional spheres embedded in $\mathbb R^d$ which satisfies all and only the intersections in $E$?

Comment: The problem is similar to that of specifying for each $i,j$ whether or not $S_i$ is inside $S_j$, where now the spheres need not have the same radius. Felsner, Trotter, and Fishburn showed that some specifications could not be achieved in any dimension. See http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~felsner/Paper/sphere.pdf.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not misunderstanding, 
it could be that this $\mathbb{R}^2$ example shows that $S_5$
cannot simultaneously satisfy these relationships:
\begin{eqnarray}
S_1 \cap S_2 & \subset & S_5 \\
S_3 \cap S_4 & \subset & S_5 \\
S_2 \cap S_3 & \not\subset & S_5 \\
S_1 \cap S_4 & \not\subset & S_5 \\
\end{eqnarray}

---

[image: Circ5]

          

<sup>Here four circles have same radii, but in general the radii may differ.</sup>

---

This is related to [OEIS A250001](https://oeis.org/A250001).
I recall that Jonathan Wild proved the impossibility of the above configuration,
but I have no reference.
This example may not resolve your question, because
I am uncertain if Wild's conditions on drawing circles
are exactly
equivalent to your intersection relations.

Comment: It actually looks relevant, thanks! 
Are you aware of any multi-dimensional extension of this?

Comment: @Alfred: I am unaware of extensions to $\mathbb{R}^d$ for $d \ge 3$. It is already quite difficult for $\mathbb{R}^2$: $16951$ ways to draw $5$ circles!